# centering issues with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap and running into the issue of elements not centering correctly. I will set a margin-left and right auto and it won't do nothing. Anyone have any advice? An example of what i'm referring to can be seen within my footer at [code]http://192.185.183.130/~cedarlak/[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the width from .footer-container

```
.footer-container {
width: 1170px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: in the footer: do you want the nav ul with text in the center or do you want the responsive nav in the center?

Comment: I want to center the nav UL menu

Comment: okay. add text-align: center; to the div containing the ul#menu-footer_menu. then add display: inline-block; and float: none; to ul with id="menu-footer_menu"

Comment: I still cannot seem to get it to work after doing what you instructed.